# MySQL: grant SELECT to all databases except system

Tags: mysql

I need to add an user able to read all my databases.
So I create:

```
create user 'reader' identified by 'password';
grant select on *.* to 'reader';
```

The problem with this is that the user is able to read also system tables like mysql.user, which I think is a security problem.
I tried to revoke the select privilege on that table:

```
revoke SELECT ON mysql.* from 'reader';
```

But I get

```
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'reader';
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to achieve what I want? 
Or manipulating the grant tables is the only way?

Comment: You can revoke only right existed as standalone one (remove record from grants table). Grant `SELECT ON mysql.*` not exist (no such record), so operation fails. it's revoke, not deny.

Answer (score 0):

may i correct what you have posted above..

"create user 'reader' identified by 'password';
grant select on *.* to 'reader';"

try below

create user reader@whatEverIPAddressOfUser identified by 'password'; 
grant select on *.* to reader@whatEverIPAddressOfUser; 
flush privileges;

then issue your revoke statement

revoke SELECT ON mysql.* from reader@whatEverIPAddressOfUser;
flush privileges;